# Multiple textbox controls on session object possible?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, session

I'm looking to redirect a user to a static form so they can review their user profile info before it is submitted, and I've been told a session object is the way to do this, but I have not seen how/if it is possible to use it for multiple controls (I have textboxes, dropdowns, radiobuttons, etc). Is it possible, and if so, what does the syntax look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store your control value in a session variable like..

```
Session["TextboxValue"] = textboxes.Text;
Session["TextboxValue"] = dropdowns.SelectedItem.Text;
```

and then access value when you want to get it..

```
String TextboxValue = Session["TextboxValue"]
```

Comment: So, if I need to show the user's inputted name, I would write Session["Name"] = TextBox1.Text; under the page load block, and then String Name = Session["Name"]... where do I put this line? I want to display it in the redirect page.

Comment: you can create label on that page where you want to show these values. then assign to label. e.g. Label1.Text = Session["Name"];

Answer (score 0):

For each type instance you have to use the following syntax:

```
Session["Type"] = typeInstance;

typeInstance = (Type) Session["Type"];
```